# Adding one image on top of another in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

Is there a function in Processsing that I can use to add and overlay an image onto another image?

So for example, I could have loaded 2 images into 2 separate PImage like so:

```
PImage image1 = loadImage("imagefile1.jpg");
PImage image2 = loadImage(imagefile2.jpg");
```

Now, how do I add `image2` into `image1` so that `image2` appears to be on top of `image1`, and then save the whole edited `image1` as a new image?

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is! Just [copy](http://processing.org/reference/PImage_copy_.html):

```
image1.copy(image2, 0, 0, image2.width, image2.height, 0, 0, image2.width, image2.height);
image1.save("copied.jpg");
```

or if you want to [blend](http://processing.org/reference/PImage_blend_.html) them...

```
image1.blend(image2, 0, 0, image2.width, image2.height, 0, 0, image2.width, image2.height, ADD); 
image1.save("blended.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks! My `image2` is a png file with transparency. Apparently, when copy, the transparent pixels become black colour on `image1`. Is it possible to maintain the transparency pixels of `image2` in `image1`?

Comment: If I recall correctly, that's a known bug (but my information may be out of date). You can loop through `image1.pixels` and `image2.pixels` and do the copy yourself, using an `if` statement that checks the transparency using `alpha()`.